# Titanium: Upgraded to XCode5 and iOS 7 SDK and this broke

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I am using Appcelerators Titanium to build my app. I've been using it for a while now and it's worked fine. A particular piece of code stopped working when I upgraded to the latest Ti SDK (3.1.3 GA) and Xcode 5 with iOS7 SDK.

The lines that don't work anymore involve the WebView.

```
imageData  = generateURL(win.vforumLocation + 'slide' + (id + 1) + '.pdf', 600);
//-- assume imageData is a valid URL that gets generated.
portWV.url = imageData; //-- portrait webview
landWV.url = imageData; //-- landscape webview
```

Those 3 lines worked fine up until I upgraded. Basically the two webviews are loading the same URL.

What I was experiencing after the upgrade was only one web view was loading the url so what I did was:

```
imageData   = generateURL(win.vforumLocation + 'slide' + (id + 1) + '.pdf', 600);
//-- assume imageData is a valid URL that gets generated.
portWV.url  = imageData; //-- portrait webview
setTimeout(function(){
    landWV.url = imageData; //-- landscape webview
},500);
```

a basic timeout call on the other `.url` prop and bam, it worked. Any idea what is going on here? I'd rather not add this timeout.

**Update**
Just testing around a bit, I tried changing the URL of what was being loaded like so:

```
imageData   = generateURL(win.vforumLocation + 'slide' + (id + 1) + '.pdf', 600);
portWV.url  = imageData;
imageData   = generateURL(win.vforumLocation + 'slide' + (id + 2) + '.pdf', 600);
landWV.url = imageData;
```

In the case above, both web views load, with the obvious reason they are no longer both the same slide

Comment: Have you tried attaching an 'error' eventListener to the webView which does not load the content? Does it throw an error? If yes, what does it say?

Comment: I did, I get nothing from that event

Answer (score 0):

Although not particularly a solution for your original question, you could get around using setTimeout by attaching a eventListener to the portWV, firing on the 'load' event.

```
portWV.addEventListener('load', function() {
    landWV.url = imageData;
});
```

Either way, one possible solution could be to use only one web view and check for orientation changes to adjust its size...

Comment: I would use only one web view but the problem is when the user does a pinch/zoom in landscape and switches back to portrait the portrait view is zoomed way in. I'm trying to find a solution that will reset the zoom upon rotation but so far no luck. I think I'm going to work more towards that then use two web views. If I cant get that, this could work